# How to pass metatags from a node into a view?

Tags: 7, views, entities, meta-tags

I'm sending the information of my node into an external application and I need to be able to send the meta tags of that node as well. Unfortunately, I do not see the meta tag fields.

My question is...

- How can I send my meta tags into a view?

**NOTE: I'm using the [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/th/project/metatag), I have seen few posts that suggest using the [metatags_quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) module to add this functionality. However, I need to be able to do it with the instead [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/th/project/metatag)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sandbox project call [Metatag Views Field](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/ciss/2228751), which provide metatags as a field into Views.